# Node synchronization

Tags: go-ethereum

The question is about the node, is the node functionality enough in fast synchronization for the functioning of a centralized exchange? Or is it necessary to download a node in full synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in the history then fast node should be enough, I guess. Fast sync basically just ignores the history and starts full sync from the present time, approximately.

On the other hand if I was to run an exchange I wouldn't want to have to trust the past history checkpoints of fast sync and I'd want to verify the past data myself so I'd run a full node. The cost of running a full node is insignificant compared to all the other costs of running an exchange.

Comment: for fast synchronization, need write geth --syncmode = fast?

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options

Comment: Fast sync is the default sync mode in Geth.